# Section by row count

Tags: cognos

Im trying to evenly split row count by "X" number of sections set as a parameter. So for example:

Report returns 1000 rows, I need to have 3 sections with 333,333 and 334 rows.

set to 5 sections, 200,200,200,200 and 200.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any particular Cognos product?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a data item called 'Total Row Count' with the following expression, substituting [data item] with an actual attribute data item from the query:

   ```
   count([data item] for report)
   ```
2. Create a data item called 'Row Number' with the following expression, again substituting [data item] with an actual attribute data item from the query:

   ```
   running-count([data item])
   ```
3. Assuming that you are using a passed in numeric parameter named 'sections', create another data item called 'Section' with the following expression:

   ```
   ceiling([Row Number]/([Total Row Count]/?sections?))
   ```

The result is the data item [Section] will contain the section number for each row. In your example above with 1000 rows divided by 5 sections, rows 1 - 199 will have a [Section] number of 1. Rows 200 - 399 will get a section number of 2 etc. You can then section your output by breaking on the [Section] attribute.